# How come Facebook Graph API does not show information similar to the webpage?

Tags: facebook, api, http, rest, facebook-graph-api

I'm logged in as Facebook. I go to a random user's profile, and I see his music/movies/activities.

```
http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1309170520
```

But when I hit it using the graph API , I get an empty json.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/1309170520/movies?access_token=XXXX
```

Comment: hi have you taken the extended permission for that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the extended permission "friend_likes" (and you may also want "user_likes" to get the current users likes).  Facebook has a blog post about getting the [movies your friends like using the graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/481/) that shows you how to get this info.